# How to convert a String to Mongo Document?

Tags: rust, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a Document using a String to query a mongo collection.

Something like this

```
let query = r#"{ "_id": 3249883475987345844 }"#

let filter = Document::from_String(query);
let cursor = collection.find(filter).await;
```

I cannot use the `doc!` macro because the query is also unknown.

```
let from_config = r#"{ "age": { "$gte": 20 } }"#
```

In the rust Bson documentation there is a method `Document::from_reader` that requires a Bson byte stream. But it does not clearly explain how to create a bson byte stream. There is also a `RawDocumentBuf` that can convert to document but it also requires a bson byte stream. Bson also has a method `to_document` but it only return a document if itself is already one. I am starting to feel that this was an intentional design to not allow database attacks.

Comment: And you are aware of DB attacks, are you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `bson` does not support deserializing from string with JSON syntax, but it does support serializing any `serde`-serializable object into a document, and `serde_json` provides us a type (`serde_json::Value`) we can deserialize from generic JSON string and is also serializable:

```rust
let query = r#"{ "_id": 3249883475987345844 }"#;
let filter = serde_json::from_str::<serde_json::Value>(query).expect("invalid BSON");
let filter = bson::to_document(&filter).expect("invalid BSON");
```